# How to reduce/specify number of connections in celery flower?

Tags: celery, django-celery, flower

I am running an app on a limited service host, where my Redis server has a maximum of 50 connections. I have configured my web app to be using a consistent 20 Redis connections. However, if I launch Flower to inspect the Redis, my connections jump up to 45. How can I reduce how many connections Flower is launching?

I thought I found a way by making my flower start command:

```
celery -A myapp flower --redis_max_connections=2 --concurrency=4 -l info
```

But this didn't seem to change anything... What am I missing?